# System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute does not have Order, what is the alternative?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I created an attribute inherited from ActionFilterAttribute using System.Web.Http.Filters.

I searched about it and found that `Order` property is just defined in System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute.

How to order attributes actions in System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute ?